# ElasticSearch: mappings for fields that are sorted often

Tags: elasticsearch

Suppose I have a field "epoch_date" that will be sorted often when I do Elastic Search queries. How should I map this field? Right now, I just have stored: yes. Should I index it even though this field will not count towards the relevancy scoring? What should I add to this field if I intend to sort on this field often, so it will be more efficient?

```
{
    "tweet" : {
        "properties" : {
            "epoch_date" : {
                "type" : "integer",
                "store" : "yes"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's nothing you need to change to sort on the field given your mapping. You can only sort on a field if it's indexed, and the default is `"index":"yes"` for numeric or dates. You can not set a numeric type to `analyzed`, since there's no text to analyze. Also, better to use the date type for a date instead of the integer.

Sorting can be memory expensive if your field you are sorting on has a lot of unique terms. Just make sure you have enough memory for it. Also, keep in mind that sorting on a specific field you throw away the relevance ranking, which is a big part of what a search engine is all about.

Whether you want to store the field too doesn't have anything to do with sorting, but just with the way you retrieve it in order to return it together with your search results. If you use the [`_source`](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/reference/mapping/source-field/) field (default behaviour) there's no reason to store specific fields. If you ask for specific fields using the [`fields`](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/reference/api/search/fields/) option when querying, then the stored fields would be retrieved directly from lucene rather than extracted from the `_source` field parsing the json.

Answer (score 0):

An index is used for efficient sorting. So YES, you want to create an index for the field.

As to needing it to be "more efficient", I'd kindly advise you to first check your results and see if they're fast enough. I don't see a reason beforehand (with the limited info you provided) to think it wouldn't be efficient.

If you intend to filter on the field as well (date-ranges?) be sure to use filters instead of queries whenever you feel the filters used will be used often. This because filters can be efficiently cached.

Comment: Should I set it to "index": analyzed" in the mapping then?

Comment: You want to pass integers verbatim so without analysis: `index:"not_analyzed"` See http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/reference/mapping/core-types/. Another way would be to use the `date` datatype (see that same url).

Comment: Have a look at my answer. `analyzed` or `not_analyzed` don't make any sens with fields that are not of string `string`. The index option can only be set to yes or no.

Comment: @javanna is right indeed. Not sure what I was smoking in the comment.

Comment: Re-reading my comment and all its typos, I think I was smoking something too :)